# What does it mean when Function pointer type is used as a function?

Tags: c++, casting, function-pointers

In the following C++ code:

```
typedef void (*FuncPtr)(void);    // FuncPtr typedef

void foo(void){...}               // some function

void bar(FuncPtr ptr){...}        // take FuncPtr type as an argument

void main(void)
{
    bar(FuncPtr(foo));            // where bar is used
}
```

What does `FuncPtr(foo)` mean in calling `bar`?

Is this a way just to cast `foo` to `FuncPtr` type? But why not use `(FuncPtr)foo`?

And is this a feature only in C++, or both in C?

Comment: Read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast

Comment: You could also just use `bar(foo);`.

Comment: `FuncPtr(foo)` and `(FuncPtr)foo` are equivalent  - both are an explicit conversion of `foo` to `FuncPtr` - except that `FuncPtr(foo)` is specific to C++ and `(FuncPtr)foo` is valid in both C and C++ (albeit often discouraged in C++). Since `foo()` is a function of type `void(*)()` [accepts no arguments and returns `void`] and `FuncPtr` is a `typedef` of `void(*)()`, the conversion does nothing.   `main()` could have just as easily done `bar(foo)` or `bar(&foo)` (which are equivalent since a function name in an expression is implicitly converted to a pointer to that function).

Answer (score 2):

`FuncPtr(foo)` casts `foo` to a `FuncPtr`. It does the same thing as `(FuncPtr)foo`.

`foo` already has the correct type. So, `bar(foo);` does the job and should be preferred.

`FuncPtr(foo)` is only valid in C++. `(FuncPtr)foo` is valid in both languages.